# Avoid SSL certificate when developing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ssl, iis-7, https

I'm developing a Chrome Extension to add some functionality to Gmail. My problems start when I want to show an Iframe which contains a "non certificated" page (`http` instead of `https`). I've tried to publish my page to an IIS 7 server using SSL but the Javascript returns an error because I don't have a SSL certificate.

I've tried to run Chrome with the `--allow-running-insecure-content` tag, but it isn't work for the javascript security exceptions.

My question is: is it possible to develop without the certificate and buy it later?

**Edit**: The exact JavaScript error is:

`Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:1851" from accessing a frame with origin "https://mail.google.com".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "https". Protocols must match.`

Comment: If the JS error talks about "mixed content" you can run the code by selecting the shield icon near the browser's address bar and selecting "allow".

Comment: First, you can get a certificate for free from [StartCom](https://www.startssl.com/). It will be trusted by most desktop and mobile browsers. Second, regarding "is it possible to develop without the certificate..." . You may be able to do it (its technically possible, but clients will probably reject the setup). Set up a SSL server, and then *only* provide Anonymous Diffie-Hellman (ADH) at the server. ADH does not send a server cert, but still uses SSL. Chrome will probably reject it with a "no shared cipher suites" error. And don't do it in production.

Comment: I'm going to try with the ADH, but I can't find much information to configure IIS7 to use it. @Andy: I've edited my question to include the exact js error. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

I've run my web application in SSL mode, like they say in this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/723357/Enabling-SSL-with-IIS-Express-in-Visual-Studio), without using any certificate. When the javascript error appeared in the console, I just copied the url that causes the error (`https://localhost/...`) and loaded it in a new tab, ignoring the Chrome security warning. Then I've reloaded the Gmail page and, voilà, works like a champ.

It is necessary to repeat the proccess every time that Chrome is executed.

Comment: So, effectively, `localhost` **has** a certificate then (even if it's auto-generated by IIS), since you're talking to it using `https://`. Browsers tend not to enable anonymous cipher suites by default, so you wouldn't be able to add the exception without one.

Comment: Probably the certificate is generated by Visual Studio or IIS Express, but I don't really care as long I can work without buy or install any certificate and be able to debug my project in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

i think you should upload your project on server, you face some security issues when you try to access from your local host

Comment: Which security issues? I know that uploading my project on a certificated server will solve the problem, but I want to develop in my localhost.

Comment: try to use self signed certificate on your localhost. you will find details on your lamp or xampp about self signed certificate

Comment: Again, this is not "avoid SSL certificate". Thank you, but I've found the solution.